# Ayuda carrusel imagenes (php,custom fields)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Buenas tengo la siguiente duda, he creado este carrousel de imagenes cogiendo los datos de custom fields. El caso que en la imagen, no aplica el link que corresponde y no sale ninguna imagen en el carrousel.

Anteriormente si hago un var_dump($casosexitoespecificos['imagen']), si que muestra los link correctamente.

El nombre_cliente y descripcion lo muestra correctamente.

```
<?php $carousel = '[vc_row][vc_column][ultimate_carousel slide_to_scroll="single" title_text_typography="" slides_on_mob="1" autoplay_speed="3000" el_class="carousel-sectores" dots="off" item_space="0"]'; ?>

<?php foreach ($casos_exito_carrousel as $casoexitoespecifico) {

        $carousel = $carousel.'[vc_single_image image="'.$casoexitoespecifico["imagen"].']';
        $carousel = $carousel.'[vc_column_text]'.$casoexitoespecifico["nombre_cliente"].'[/vc_column_text]';
        $carousel = $carousel.'[vc_column_text]'.$casoexitoespecifico["descripcion"].'[/vc_column_text]';
}?>

<?php $carousel = $carousel.'[/ultimate_carousel][/vc_column][/vc_row]'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

no estas cerrando el código de la imagen:

Tu código:

```
'[vc_single_image image="'.$casoexitoespecifico["imagen"].']';
```

Lo correcto (pienso)

```
'[vc_single_image image="'.$casoexitoespecifico["imagen"].'"]';
```

Comment: Al añadir las comillas que me propones, la imagen desaparece. Si no carga el link correcto pone una imagen de (no-img) que hay en el servidor